# How can I add an effect so hovering over an SVG element makes it larger?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an complex svg file with many different elements. I want to add an effect to some of the elements (or groups of elements) so they become larger when hovered over. When the pointer leaves their area, they should go back to their original size.  What's a good way to do this?

I can create a hidden copy of the elements in large and show them on hover and hide them afterwards, but is there a better way to do this? I can use a library if there's one that's very helpful for this.

Comment: I think Snap.svg would be something you would be interested in:

http://snapsvg.io/

Comment: d3.js is really great for this.  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example that does what you are looking for with D3.js.  It's a big library but really worth learning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div id="viz"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);    

sampleSVG.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 14)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "green")
        .transition()                      
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", 28);})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .transition()                      
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", 14);})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will that work on a single svg element that's part of a complex svg file?

Comment: Yes, as long as you give the svg element an id and then add d3.select("#myid").  Or add a class if you have many of them.  The mouseover will work on any elements with the class.